# refresh datagrid of parent form from child form

Tags: c#

```
//Adding Data to Database Here.      
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO itemDB(brname, itmname, itmunit,itmgr, itmmrp, itmbyp, itmdlrp, itmtx, itmdlrmrg, itmrtmrg, itmusrcode, active) VALUES (@label11, @label4, @label6, @label14, @label2, @label9, @label10, @label8, @label12, @label13, @label7, @label3)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label11", combobrand.GetItemText(combobrand.SelectedItem));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label4", itemname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label6", combouom.GetItemText(combouom.SelectedItem));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label14", itemkgs.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label2", itemmrp.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label9", itembrp.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label10", itemslp.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label8", itemtax.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label12", itemdlmargin.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label13", itemretailmargin.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@label7", itemcode.Text);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@label3", status);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

combobrand.SelectedIndex = -1;
combouom.SelectedIndex = -1;
itemname.Text = "";
itemunit.Text = "";
itemmrp.Text = "";
itembrp.Text = "";
itemslp.Text = "";
itemtax.Text = "";
itemdlmargin.Text = "";
itemretailmargin.Text = "";
itemcode.Text = "";

MessageBox.Show("Record Saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
con.Close();
```

This form is for adding data. After pressing close button I want to refresh my parent form datagrid.

**Loading data to datagrid which is in form1**

```
 Public void dataload()
 {
  con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM[dbo].              [itemDB]", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["itmcode"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["brname"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["itmname"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["itmunit"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["itmgr"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["itmml"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["itmpc"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["itmtx"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["itmbyp"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item["itmdlrmrg"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["itmrtmrg"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[11].Value = item["itmdlrp"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[12].Value = item["itmmrp"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[13].Value = item["itmusrcode"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[14].Value = item["active"].ToString();

        }
        con.Close();
 }
```

> form1 datagrid is not refreshing after adding data in form 2. For
>   refreshing I added one new button in form1 and by click that button i
>   am refreshing data of datagrid.
>   That dataload function i created for loading data to datagrid. I am calling 
>   this function where ever I needed.

Comment: Maybe this example can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406560/how-to-refresh-parent-form-when-in-child-form-is-button-clicked

Comment: That link what you gave not helped for me. any other examples may be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

So first you need to make the datagridView in parent form to be public and the override the OnClosed event on the form that you use to add data by following code:

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        foreach (var item in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection connection= new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand(SelectStatement,connection));
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }
            if (item.GetType()==typeof(parentForm))
            {
                (item as Form1).dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is too confusing answer for a beginner (which OP evidently is) and can be solved much elegantly than this. First of all, why override `OnClosed` event? It can be done on `FormClosed` or `FormClosing` events. Or maybe on some button click. And going through `OpenForms` collection? It is much easier to pass reference to parent form through constructor or property

Answer (score 0):

Since you provided almost no code, I'll assume you have "parent form" `Form1` which opens `Form2`.

`Form2` inserts data with command you supplied.

One way is to show `Form2` as dialog form (form that is on top of another an you can't click beneath it). When that form closes successfully (with record saved into database), refresh grid on parent form (`Form1`).

So, on `Form2` (child form), after data is inserted, set form's `DialogResult`, like this:

```
//... removed previous statements for brevity
MessageBox.Show("Record Saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
con.Close();

//record is inserted, now return DialogResult "OK", so that the parent form can refresh grid
//this also closes this child, insert form

this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

On parent form, after opening child form, you should check for child form's `DialogResult`. If that result is OK, refresh grid. 
On your parent form, code should be something like this:

```
Form2 frmInsert = new Form2();
DialogResult dr = frmInsert.ShowDialog();
if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataload();
}
else
{
    //nothing, user didn't insert anything on insert form
}
```

---

Another way is to fire event from child form. That allows you to show child form anyway you want (not necessarily as dialog form) and just wait for event to be fired so you can refresh grid.

On child form add `EventHandler` named `RefreshNeeded`, like this (in the form's scope)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    //event handler
    public EventHandler RefreshNeeded;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //... rest of form's code...
```

On your child form (`Form2`), fire event when data is inserted (lets say on `btnInsert_Click`):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //... removed previous statements for brevity
    MessageBox.Show("Record Saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    con.Close();

    //after data is saved, fire event!
    RefreshNeeded?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

On parent form, you have to subcribe to event, and add method that is executed when event is fired:

```
Form2 frmInsert = new Form2();
//subscribe to event
frmInsert.RefreshNeeded += new EventHandler(RefreshGrid);
frmInsert.Show();

//....

private void RefreshGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    dataload();
}
```

That should be it. Feel free to ask if you have some questions.

Comment: I tried What You told. But No result came. Datagridview not refreshed

Comment: @vijay Edit your question and show us some relevant code, not just sql command.

Comment: @vijay there's no useful code here. Please, put actual methods and method calls which are used for populating grid and opening child form, **not** sql statement. I cannot explain simpler than I did, so if you're still unable to implement my answer, please show us code and maybe we can work it out.

Comment: @vijay I have edited my answer and added calls to `dataload()` method where needed. I also saw that you do not clear already populated grid, so I have added `dataGridView.Rows.Clear()` method. You should add that clearing at the beginning of your `dataload` method. Try now and tell us results.

Comment: @ Nino, I didexactly what you told above. but my datagrid is not refreshing.